# How do I pass by reference char * foo[SIZE][SIZE] to a function and dereference it?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm really having a difficult time understanding how to pass the address of a 2D array of char pointers to a function, and actually assigning a value to it.

```
void fillWithStrings( 'pointer to foo'  ){ // How to do this part?
   for( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
       for( int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++ ) {
           char * temp = malloc( sizeof(char) * 3 );
           temp = "hi";
           *foo[i][j] = temp; // And this part?
       }
   }
}

int main(){
   char * foo[SIZE][SIZE];

   fillWithStrings( &foo );

   return 0;
}
```

And yes, it is easier to fill **foo** in the scope where it was declared, but the point is, how to do it inside another function?

Comment: then calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   Remember that every call to `malloc()` should be matched by a call to `free()`.  Do not depend on the OS to cleanup after your code.

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference. Only pass-by-value.

Comment: OT: This `temp = "hi";` leaks the memory allocated by the call in the line before.

Comment: Please elaborate why actually you want to pass down a *pointer* to `foo`. From the code you show there is no need to do so. Passing `foo`'s value would perfectly be sufficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the first part the replace `'pointer to foo'` with `char* (*foo)[SIZE][SIZE]`
This breaks down as follows:

`(*foo)` means foo is a pointer to something,
`(*foo)[SIZE][SIZE]` means foo points to a 2D array of somethings,
`char* (*foo)[SIZE][SIZE]` means foo points to a 2D array of pointers to char.

The use of the parentheses is necessary to avoid this being interpreted as a 2D array of pointers to pointers to char.

For the second part, `(*foo)[i][j] = temp;`

`(*foo)` will get the original array foo points to and
`(*foo)[i][j]` specifies where in that array the assignment will go.

EDIT: fixed second part and added explanations

Comment: Thank you. If you have the time, could you please explain what is happening on char * (*foo)? Is it by any chance dereferencing the value of foo before assigning it to a char *?

Comment: You use one indirection too much. For a 2D array, use a pointer to 1D array. That is also the type you get for a 2D array parameter.

Comment: How would this `*foo[i][j] = temp;`  make sense? ***If*** (for what ever reasons) `foo`s address would have been passed down (as per the 1st part of you answer), addressing the elements its points would need to be done like this: `(*foo)[i][j]`

Comment: "*will get the original array*" this still isn't quiet right. Using dereferencing `(*foo)` you get to what the array decayed to, that is the address of its 1st element.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is **no such thing** as *passing by reference in **C***. Everything is *passed by value*. An array is "passed" as pointer to its first element. This pointer is also passed *by value*. It is being copied as function argument, but the array that it points at *is left as it is*, and can be seen from your function.

`char * foo[SIZE][SIZE]` is a two-dimensional array of character pointers. These pointers may point to charactres or arrays of characters. Since there is no specifiation of the size of these arrays of characters, from your code `fillWithStrings()` it can be assumed that these arrays are intended to be `\0` terminated strings of characters. 
Running this demonstration code may help better understand what is going on in your function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 4

void fillWithStrings( char* (foo)[SIZE][SIZE]  ){ 

   for( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
       for( int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++ ) {
           char * temp = malloc( 3 ); //sizeof(char) is always 1
           if (j % 2)  strcpy(temp, "lo");
           else strcpy(temp,"hi");      
           foo[i][j] = temp;
       }        
   }  
}


int main(){
   char * foo[SIZE][SIZE];

   fillWithStrings( foo );

   for( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i ++)
       for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
          printf("[%d][%d] = %s\n", i, j, foo[i][j]);  

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays cannot be assigned (in C). Use `strcpy(temp, ...)` instead of `temp = ...`.

Comment: Thanks, @alk. I followed the suggestion on `strcpy`. Still I'm not sure about the SIZE*SIZE memory leak, how it can get fixed within OP's code idea?

Comment: The leaks resulted from using the assignment `temp = ...` which overwrote the address of the memory allocated by the call to `malloc()`, which made this very memory leak, as the one and only "reference" to it is lost. So replacing the assignments by the calls to `strcpy()`  also removed the leakage. :-)

Comment: This is a **really** great point, @alk. Thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass the address of `foo` to `fillWithStrings()`, as the function does not want to change the value of `foo` (which, BTW, wouldn't even be possible as `foo` is an array).

Just pass `foo`, which then would decay to a pointer to is 1st element. It's 1st element is a `char * [SIZE]`, the address to the latter is `char * (*) [SIZE]`.

Code doing so might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE (7)

int array_init(char * (*a)[SIZE])
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
    {
      a[i][j] = calloc(42, sizeof *(a[i][j])); /* Allocate 42 times the size of 
                                               what (a[i][j]) points , that is a char.*/
      if (NULL == a[i][j])
      {
        return -1;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  char * a[SIZE][SIZE] = {0};

  if (-1 == array_init(a))
  {
    perror("array_init() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Do stuff. */

  /* Free a's elements here. */

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This should work:

```
typedef char *FOO_TYPE [SIZE][SIZE];  // Or whatever your size/name is

void fillWithStrings (FOO_TYPE& foo)
{
}
```

You can then use it exactly as if it were declared locally.

Comment: This is a C question.

Comment: this question was about C programming and this answer is how to do it in C++.  C++ is a whole different language.